# Why (if) extension methods overload generic ones?

Tags: c#

I have two methods for sorting - an extension method for int arrays and generic method.

I cannot call the generic method for sorting int arrays even if I use it as a parameter. Any help?

```
{
            string[] catNames = { "Lucky","Bella","Luna","Oreo","Simba","Toby","Loki","Oscar" };

            int[] numbers = { 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 234, 54, 14, 653,3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",Sort(catNames)));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", Sort(numbers))); //THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I GET ERROR! CANNOT CALL THE GENERIC METHOD HERE. THANK YOU!


        }

        public static void Sort(this int[] array)
        {
            … bubble sort...
        }

        public static T[] Sort<T>(T[] array) where T:IComparable<T>
        {
            … bubble sort ...
        }
```

Comment: Does `numbers.Sort()` work? What is the complete error message you get?

Comment: The extension method is _not_ being treated as an extension method. Remove “this” to make it apparent it is being _used as a normal static method_ - extension methods only apply when invoked on instances, where `e.Ext(..) -> Ext(e, ..)`. This will lead to a more focused title and question..

Comment: When I run your code, the generic method is called in both cases. Please provide a working sample that reproduces the issue, or add more description for the error you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Second writeline should be modified to below

```cs
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers.Sort()));
```

Comment: I know :), it works that way. But if I call Sort(someIntArray), extension method Is called again. I want generic to be called (intellisense sees it), but compiler always infers to the extension one